# How do I place an icon on top-right position of CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, android-xml, android-cardview

It changes its position with lesser width.

I want it standard for all screens.

Comment: Better  use constraint layout and align to end and top.

Comment: <cardview><constraintlayout><image /> ... other elements... </constraintlayout></cardview>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CardView is inherited from FrameLayout, so you can make something like:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />
```

But for more accuracy and flexibility i propose this variant:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this below code.change your src file in imageView

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15sdp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/com_facebook_blue"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_checkbox_selected" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: what in the world is sdp?

Comment: You can use dp for that